# Условное форматирование при условии Not IsNull [поле_типа_datetime] срабатывает всегда Access 2003

Tags: ms-access

Поле берётся из таблицы и является источником данных для текстбокса, в котором я хочу применить условное форматирование. Почти всегда оно имеет значение `NULL`. 
Выражение для условного форматирования:

```
Not IsNull([duedate])
```

Всегда возвращает истину, не понимаю почему. Поле `[duedate]` принадлежит родительской форме.

Comment: покажите запрос в конструкторе. может `Not: IsNull([duedate])` или что то не досказали

Comment: Это и есть запрос в конструкторе.

Comment: по формату после NOT должно быть `:` может из этого?

Comment: Не думаю, что должно быть двоеточие. Во-первых нигде такого не видел, а во-вторых аксесс ругается на синтаксис.

Comment: если на синтаксис, тогда попробуйте `proverka: Not isNull([duedate])`

Comment: Нашёл подходящее решение - [использование в выражении условного форматирования функции, определённой в коде формы](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865245/conditional-fomatting-on-continuous-forms-using-vbaaccess-2003)